# chrome crashed error on jenkins and Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-18.04

```
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'QA-Ubuntu-Droplet', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-66-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_252'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5585ac7a25b9 <unknown>
```

My Code for chrome :

```
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            options.addArguments("--window-size=1366,768");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I have also run command `chmod +x chromedriver` and `chmod +x google-chrome`.

Have look at lot of different answers and applied all the possible solutions but still error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with adding additional arguments:

```
--disable-dev-shm-usage
--disable-gpu
```

Comment: Hi, can you please look at this my question and help me if you have solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607750/chrome-is-not-stable-on-my-jenkins-and-ubuntu-18-04