# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed using ChromeDriver Selenium in Jenkins on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-18.04

Chrome is not stable on my Jenkins. When I run build 5 times, it runs 1 - 2-time success, and the other 3 times I have the above error.

Snapshot of the error:
[image]

Code for Chrome :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://mywebsite.com");
```

Some steps I have already taken :

1. Provided 777 permission to google chrome and chrome driver
2. Set : Start Xvfb before the build, and shut it down after to True in Jenkins build setting
   [image]
3. ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69
4. Google Chrome 81.0.4044.129
5. Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-99-generic x86_64)

Comment: do you execute parallel tests? if yes how many. did you try with --disable-gpu flag ?

Comment: Yes I did. @Infern0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

[image: snapshot]

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

### Deep dive

Looking into the snapshot of the error stacktrace you have provided, though you mentioned about using *ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69* and *Google Chrome 81.0.4044.129*, still it appears there is a mismatch between the versions of the different binaries you are using, possibly *Chrome* browser is not installed at the default location within your system or due to JDK mismatch. Additionally, *ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69 (2020-03-17)* was a bit unstable which was replaced by [ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.138 (2020-05-05)](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/81.0.4044.138/notes.txt)

However, the server i.e. *ChromeDriver* expects you to have *Chrome* installed in the *default location* for each system as per the image below:

[image: Chrome_binary_expected_location]

<sup>1</sup>For Linux systems, the ChromeDriver expects `/usr/bin/google-chrome` to be a symlink to the actual Chrome binary.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [What is default location of ChromeDriver and for installing Chrome on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788257/what-is-default-location-of-chromedriver-and-for-installing-chrome-on-windows/49795348#49795348)

---

### Solution

In case you are using the *Chrome* executable in a non-standard location you have to *override the Chrome binary location* as follows:

- Code based solution:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.setBinary('/usr/bin/google-chrome');    //chrome binary location
  options.addArguments("--headless");
  options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
  options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  //execute the remaining steps
  driver.quit();
  ```
- Additional considerations- Ensure the following:

  - *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [**JDK 8u251**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
  - *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
  - *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v81.0.4044.138](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=81.0.4044.138/) level.
  - *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v80.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/81.0.4044.138/notes.txt))
  - *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
  - Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
  - Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t/50642913#50642913)
- [How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462#49582462)
- [Running Chromedriver on Ubuntu Server headlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500700/running-chromedriver-on-ubuntu-server-headlessly/49505381#49505381)

Comment: It is really detailed answer. I still not sure what I did wrong but after following this and reinstall everything worked.